# Is handler set via XSetErrorHandler global or threadlocal?

Tags: c++, linux, error-handling, x11, xlib

If I set error handler using xlib function XSetErrorHandler will this handler work for the whole process or only for a thread where XSetErrorHandler was called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work for the whole process. It is not good for more than 1 thread to communicate with Xlib, because Xlib is not thread-safe.

Comment: `XInitThreads()` should enable thread-safe mode in Xlib, if you call it before any other calls, but some versions have been buggier than others.  `XSetErrorHandler()` will still be global though.

Answer (score 2):

XSetErrorHandler is global in two senses.  One, it's not per-thread.  Two, it's not per-display: if you have multiple Display connections within the same process, the same handler will apply to all of them.